What material properties are necessary to embed a continuously rotating sphere into static space?
I am deeply intrigued by the properties of rotational connectivity in three-dimensional space, particularly as demonstrated by the Dirac-Belt Trick or Plate Trick. For a related concept, you might also refer to the Indonesian Candle Dance.
These phenomena illustrate that in 3-space, it is not a single but rather two complete rotations of an object fixed in space (e.g., a sphere with center $M$) that are topologically equivalent to no rotation at all, provided the object remains connected to its surroundings by flexible connections, such as ropes. This concept can be considered (IMHO) the most "natural" way to understand the rotational behavior in three-dimensional space.
I also recommend exploring the following Anti-twister interactive 3D-application. The Anti-twister is originally a mechanical device that utilizes the above mentioned "connectivity"-principle to, for example, supply electricity to a rotating object without relying on brushes or induction. (See Patent
Mathematically, the principles behind the Anti-twister are very universal and have found their way into many disciplines. Deeply rooted in quantum mechanics through Spinors, and in fields like engineering and computer graphics through Quaternion-Interpolation (SLERP). Although in the Antitwister-app they use a related concept called Euler-Angles.
This video demonstrates how the Dirac-Belt Trick works not only with one but with dozens of strings that don't collide with eachother. The thickness of the strings must then be shrunk to an appropriate size, ideally a line of zero-thickness.
What happens when the number of "dirac-belts" $n$ tends toward infinity?
My question under the assumption that we would end up with a continuous elastic material ("rubber") in the limit $$\lim_{n\to\infty} $$
Let $S$ be an inner sphere of radius $r$ centered at the origin. Surrounding it is a concentric outer sphere $T$ with radius $R = kr$, where $k > 1$. The outer sphere remains stationary while the inner sphere rotates around the z-axis with a small angular velocity $\omega \ll 1$, which is sufficiently low to neglect any centrifugal effects.
The space between the inner and outer spheres is filled with a flexible solid material (let's call it rubber) that is rigidly attached to both spheres.
My questions are as follows:
What material properties (such as elastic Young's modulus E, shear modulus, S, maximal strain etc.) must this rubber possess in order to safely untangle two full rotations of the inner sphere into a configuration equivalent to no rotation?
Is the "tangled" state of the rubber stable, unstable, or metastable? Specifically, if you were to fix the orientation of the inner sphere from the outside(using, for example, magnets or electric fields), rotate it twice to induce a tangled state in the rubber, and then fix the orientation again, would the rubber naturally untangle itself over time? Or would this process require a Metamaterial-like rubber to facilitate the correct repositioning of all the material's components?
Edit:
To clarify the situation I cite this explanation from the Website where you can download the Antitwister app app:

(+1) For some reason, I am not able to picture a continuously rotating sphere of gas/liquid (not a rigid body)... Could you provide a real-life example of this continuously rotating sphere of gas/liquid please, how would the molecules all rotate in a single direction? Some molecules will make big circular movements, other molecules make smaller circular movements in the same direction, and molecules at the very ends of the sphere make no movement at all... how is all this coordinated naturally in a gas/liquid (which is not a rigid body)?

There would be no gas or liquid involved at all! The rotating sphere serves just as an example for any rigid body. As for the imagination it never fails to amaze me but in theory this IS POSSIBLE. Part of why this is so hard to understand is that despite all these illustrations (Candle dance, etc.) we have no intuition for this sort of movement. (At least I dont...)
I can only recommend to try out this 3d app that I mentioned in the post.
It's fun

... one can have a rotating sphere of water in air in microgravity environment, due to surface tension (between the water molecules). But could one have a rotating sphere of water inside a larger water pool itself, not at the boundary of 2 mediums?

@ swizzmilk the issue with rigid body seems that fundamental things (e.g. electrons) probably cannot be a rigid body, which are macroscopic approximations of many smaller constituents?

I'm having trouble involving liquid into this discussion because as you say the molecules do not stay connected to each other as in a flexible material.
Yes, electrons are not rigid bodies but they are described by spinors which do share this unintuitive 720°=0° characteristic with quaternions (As I understand spinors are essentially exactly the same as quaternions). AND quaternions are used to make these animations possible. I found one other video that suggests at least in part that such a mechanism is possible IRL.

Please clarify what you mean. Why do you think that two concentric spheres with material in between that is attached to both spheres will behave in the same way as Dirac's belt, in that a rotation of 720° can be "untangled"? How do you propose this be done?

Alright! Here I must rely heavily on the animations. (particularly as mentioned in the post [this] by a youtuber named Jason Hise) and this 3d app) by the Ayn Rand Institute.
The author of the 3dApp explains how these animations are done: Quaternion Interpolation. I think (and here I REALLY hope someone would expand on this who really knows [SLERP] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slerp)) each possible orientation of a sphere is represented by a Quaternion and Quaternions live on the Hypersphere

As I understand the author of the ARI-3d-app and also some redditposts I found this paper which (again if I'm correct that's why I'm asking) describe, that it is really a continuous geodesic on the Hypersphere connecting the orientation of the outer sphere(represented by $q_0$ e.g.) over concentric spheres all the way to $q_1$ which would be the orientation of the inner sphere.

Just to be clear, by "fill with rubber" do you mean attaching them with with rubber elements that have the correct shape for the belt trick?

The belt trick can be done with more than one string. The animations show that it is even possible with hundreds of them. Now if we have an infinite number of them wouldn't we be left with a continuous volume of the same material that the dirac-belt is made out of? By rubber I just mean that this material would have to be very elastic to accomodate for all the rotations around the sphere.

You may enjoy Greg Egan's pages on this topic: https://www.gregegan.net/APPLETS/21/21.html

The Antitwister computer program did not originate with the Ayn Rand Institute, which is some sort of politics and philosophy organization like American Enterprise Institute, Cato, Hoover, Council on Foreign Relations, etc.
The website where we can download Antitwister is off a webpage consisting of links to various mathematical curiosities (“The Fourth Operation,” “Any Probability Distribution from the Uniform Distribution,” etc.), which in turn is off a webpage of various interesting articles (“The Diary of Thomas Edison,” etc.), which itself is – finally – off a webpage criticizing the Ayn Rand Institute.  An odd place to feature Antitwister perhaps but in any case let’s not confuse a critic with what he criticizes.
The beginning post says that a video by Jason Hise further extends the Dirac belt trick to many ropes.  That video does display many ropes but then so does the Antitwister program, which preceded it by many years.  Indeed the DOS version of Antitwister predated all movies in that line, including “Air On the Dirac Strings” by Louis Kaufman, et al, made three years after it.  The precedence and advantages of the Antitwister program are addressed in its About/History window.
The last correction to the beginning post is that there is nothing in the Antitwister program documentation about quaternion interpolation.  From the pictures it generates it’s obvious that “joint” (a jargon word in the program) to “joint” is linear in ordinary 3D space.
The Antitwister website mentions an elastic material that completely fills the space between the rotating ball and the stationary spherical enclosure, glued to each.  The original poster asks what mechanical properties the elastic  must have in order to survive the various motions.  For example, how much does it have to stretch?
The answer depends on the motion and the size of the ball compared to the enclosure.
In the case of the motion the Antitwister program calls “Direct Antitwister” the maximum stretching occurs after one turn of the ball.  At that time the position of the elastic is as if the ball had turned full around an axis perpendicular to its rotation axis,  the elastic passively following, twisting at the poles of the imaginary axis and wrapping about in a spiral at its equator.
Suppose the ball is half the size of the enclosing sphere.  At the start, consider a radial line of the elastic from the surface of the ball to the enclosing sphere.  After the fictitious full turn just mentioned it has stretched to an Archimedean spiral of length somewhat less than five times its original length.  As for other lines and during the full motion of “Direct Antitwister,” though I haven’t proved it, just looking at the video it’s doubtful the stretch factor would exceed what it is in that case.
Anyway, the point is that the stretch factor is finite, indeed fairly low.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Thanks for clearing this up. Will make edits as soon as possible. I was a bit confused about the origins of the app as they never mention an actual author. Presumably it would be one of those[https://ariwatch.com/WhosWho.htm] people.

Concerning quaternions: they do mention in the app that quaternions and euler-angles are related and that they don't deal with orientation space (the space that basically contains all possible rotations of the unit sphere) by multiplying quaternions but I will go over it again and make sure all the info is correct.
